# calling a function from the terminal with arguments rather the whole bash script is not working

Tags: linux, bash, shell, ubuntu, unix

```
#!/bin/bash

function main {

    [ -z "$1" ] && { getPID "$@";  } || $1

}

getPID() {

a=$1
b='service'

if [[ $a == 'contains' ]]; then
PID=$(pgrep -f  $b)
elif [[ $a == 'exact' ]]; then
PID=$(pgrep -x  $b)
fi

echo "$PID"
}


main "$@"
```

**command :** I am running for calling the function :
./script.sh  getPID contains

**Output :** it prints blank and value of variable a is blank

Comment: cut-n-paste your code (along with appropriate shebang) into [shellcheck.net](https://www.shellcheck.net/) and make the recommended change(s); if you still have issues after making the shellcheck recommended changes then come back and update the question to show a) your latest/updated code and b) the new issue(s) you're experiencing

Comment: check your script with shellcheck.net.

Comment: updated the question with the latest code and issue is it shows blank o/p  thanks

Comment: When I copy/paste the current code from your question into https://www.shellcheck.net/ it still reports issues.

Comment: tried replacing getPID; with getPID "$@"; (as suggested by shellcheck) still the output is blank

Comment: xtrace (`bash -x yourscript ...args...`, or `set -x` inside the text of the script) is a good place to start in figuring out what's going wrong.

Comment: BTW, what is the `|| $1` in your `main` function supposed to mean or do? If `$1` is a PID, then you certainly can't run it as a program.

Comment: (Also, generally, `a && b || c` is not the same as `if a; then b; else c; fi` -- use the latter when the latter is what you want; the former has side effects, like running _both_ `b` and `c` if `a` is true but `b` fails)

Comment: || $1 is the  function we are calling from cmd line

Comment: But because you're running `$1` not `"$@"`, you're leaving off the argument.

Comment: (and as others have said, you still have bugs that shellcheck would catch; please fix _all_ of them).

Comment: @NitinAlety what you're trying to do is a bad idea that will tightly couple the code inside this script to any calls of your script (whether manually or from other scripts) and introduces some unnecessary complexity in implementing your script, see https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050 for information on storing code in a variable in general. There are no existing Unix utilities that expose an interface where a user can call a function defined within the utility by name, for good reason.

Comment: @EdMorton, ...I'd argue that it _can_ be done reasonably -- you want your functions callable that way to have a reserved namespace, so, say, `cmd__foo() {` to define `foo`; then one can call `cmd__"$@"` to add the prefix to the command specified, and maybe condition the whole thing on `declare -f "cmd__$1" >/dev/null 2>&1` succeeding so you're only trying to invoke commands that really do have corresponding functions defined.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you invoke `$1` within `main` (when `$1` contains the string `getPID`), that just calls `getPID` *with no arguments*.

To pass additional arguments through to `getPID`, you should use `"$@"` instead of `$1`.